# SQL SELECT query echoing twice even with DISTINCT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am creating a simple SQL query in PHP - and for some reason, even when `DISTINCT` is used, it shows twice like this:

```
BC
BC
OH
OH
TX
TX
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `title`,`extra_fields_search` FROM `blahblah_items` WHERE catid=336 ORDER BY `blahblah_items`.`extra_fields_search` ASC ";
$partnerlisting= mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($partnerlisting))
foreach($row as $cname => $cvalue){
echo '<li>'.substr($row[extra_fields_search], 0, 2).'</li><br>';
}
;

?>
```

How can I make it so it prints out only one of each?

Comment: distinct applies to the whole ROW. if you get duplicated titles, you've probably got different values in the extra_fields_search, e.g. null + empty string.

Comment: "This SQL DISTINCT clause example would return each unique city and state combination. In this case, the DISTINCT applies to each field listed after the DISTINCT keyword."

Source: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/distinct.php

Comment: @TomWalters Thanks. Still getting used to SO etiquette. And thanks for the tip on switching to mysqli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    `title`,
    `extra_fields_search` 
FROM 
    `blahblah_items` 
WHERE 
    catid=336 
GROUP BY 
    SUBSTRING(extra_fields_search,1,2) # here. group by first two characters of extra_fields_search
    # or just "GROUP BY extra_fields_search", depends what you need
ORDER BY 
    `blahblah_items`.`extra_fields_search` ASC
```

`SELECT DISTINCT a,b FROM table` works in same way as `SELECT a,b FROM table GROUP BY a,b`

Please follow documentation:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT `title`,`extra_fields_search` 
FROM `blahblah_items` WHERE catid=336 
Group BY extra_fields_search
ORDER BY `blahblah_items`.`extra_fields_search` ASC
```

edit :
try this in your code

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($partnerlisting))
    $rows[] = $row;
    foreach($rows as $row){
    echo '<li>'.substr($row[extra_fields_search], 0, 2).'</li><br>';
    }
   ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Distinct make sure that you get unique rows. It does not make sure you will get unique column values. In your case if you consider all the fields in the result, you will notice that each row is different from the other by at least one field.

SO you will never get

```
Col1  Col2
A     B
A     B
```

But you can get

```
Col1  Col2
A     B
A     C
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT `title`, group_concat(distinct `extra_fields_search`)
FROM `blahblah_items` 
WHERE catid=336 
Group BY `title`
ORDER BY 2
```